# delete wildcard throughout subdirectories, Mac OS

Tags: wildcards, recursive, delete

I would like to delete wildcard throughout all subdirectories under the directory where I run the command.

Comment: This is not clear. It looks like you are using the word "wildcard" to describe something else. Edit the question to make it clearer. Avoid technical words.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*.unwanted' ! -type d -delete
```

Would delete the files whose name matches the `*.unwanted` wildcard (except those of type *directory*¹) in the current directory and sub-directories below. If you remove the `! -type d`, it would also remove directory files, but only if they're not empty.

Note that it also removes hidden files and files in hidden directories.

`-delete` is a BSD extension (so would work in macOS) also found in a few other `find` implementations including GNU `find` but is not standard (replace with `-exec rm -f {} +` if your `find` doesn't support it).

As the default interactive shell in macOS is now `zsh`, at the shell prompt, you should also be able to do the same with:

```
rm -f -- **/*.unwanted(D^/)   # same as find above, D for dot (hidden) files
rm -f -- **/*.unwanted(^/)    # skip hidden files and dirs
rm -f -- **/*.unwanted(-^/)   # consider the type of file after symlink resolution
rm -f -- ***/*.unwanted(^/)   # follow symlinks when traversing the
                              # directory tree (same as find -L)
```

You may however run into a *argument list too long* error if there's a large number of files, which could be worked around with `zargs` or by making the `rm` command builtin with `zmodload zsh/files`.

Both `find` predicates and zsh glob qualifiers (the part in `(...)`) can further refine which files you want to delete. Some examples:

- `-type f` / `(.)`: regular files only (in place of `! -type d` / `(^/)`)
- `-mtime -7` / `(m-7)`: not older than 7 days
- `-size +1000000c` / `(L+1000000)`: bigger than 1MB.
- `-exec cmd {} \;` / `(e['cmd $REPLY'])`, files for which `cmd` returns true.
- etc. See the `man`/`info` documentation of `find`/`zsh` for details (`info zsh qualifiers`).

---

<sup>¹ It would however remove symbolic links, whether they point to files of type directory or not</sup>